# How do I force a DIV to extend down to the bottom of the screen?

Tags: css

This is probably not possible with CSS, but maybe I'm wrong:

I have a document structure like this:

```
BODY
  DIV[A]
    DIV[B]
```

DIV[A] is `position:absolute` with fixed with and centered on screen. It has no height setting.

DIV[B] is `position:absolute` with `top:300px`. This is the actual content DIV. Inside that,  I position everything with position:absolute. Because I love position:absolute. It gives full control over positioning. No ugly text flow headaches... it's so nice.

Ok. But the problem now: DIV[B] is always only that `height` what I tell it to be. Now, maybe there's a cool CSS trick that would pull it always down to touch the bottom of the browser viewport?

Comment: Just a thought, but could you give the `div` a height of `100%` instead of a pixel size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the height to dynamically be the window height - DIV[A]'s height, you'll have to use JavaScript/jQuery and keep calling it with a `SetTimeout`.

Alternately, if it suits your needs, you can set DIV[B] to be `position:fixed; bottom:0px;`

```
<body onload="setupLayout();" >
...


  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    // ACTIVITIES TO RUN FOR THE PAGE
    function setupLayout() {
        setInterval('adjustLayout();', 1000);
    }

    // ADUST THE MAIN CONTAINER (content panel) LAYOUT
    function adjustLayout() {
        try {
            var divB = $get('divB');
            var divAHeight = 20px;
            divB.style.height = document.body.clientHeight - divAHeight ;
        }
        catch (e) { }
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: instead of having it run every second, perhaps could call it on `document.ready` and `window.resize`?

Comment: @Huey, that's a good idea. Depending on the content, you might need to also tap into `window.scroll` and control the overflow on `divB`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose DIV[A] is your header and DIV[B] your main content div and you would like to always have your content div take all the page when there is not a lot of text in it, right?

If I remember correctly, because I can't test it at the moment, you could:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

DIV[B] {
  height: 100%;
}
```

I think that should do the trick.

Edit: Here is a good example that might help you: http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/examples/csslayout1.html

Comment: Height of 100% is only considered at screen render time. Any resizing of the window will cause your layout to be undesirable.

Comment: So you're basically saying that you should keep calling a javascript function to resize the viewport

Comment: yes, that is the only way to have a div **always** be the exact size remaining in the window.

Comment: @Brad, could you look at the link I've posted and tell me what you think about it. Try to resize the window to see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

When you want DIV to be a position:absolute, it should be in a `position: relative` container.

```
<div style="position: relative">
  <div style="position: absolute; top: 300px">
    <h3>Content Header</h3>
    <!-- Content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

So regarding your problem with DIV[B], you can mix between `<table>`s and `<div>`s.

Comment: What do you mean by mixing between s and s?

Comment: sorry,between tables and divs

Answer (score 1):

```
#div_to_touch_the_bottom {
   position:fixed;
   bottom:0;
   top:0;
   left:25%;
   right:25%;
}
```

This DIV will touch the bottom of viewport, you can modify its left and right according to your needs. I am not sure that this the answer you are lookign for but it could be a good start