# How to expand left div to the remaining height?

Tags: css, xhtml, html

Basically i have:

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="sum">
little text
</div>
<div class="content">
long<br/>
long<br/>
long<br/>
long<br/>
long<br/>
long<br/>
long<br/>
text
</div>
</div>

<style>
.wrap{
height:100%;
overflow:hidden;
background:green;
}
.sum{
float:left;
height:100%;
background:yellow;
}
.content{
float:left;
height:100%;
background:red;
}
</style>
```

If you see, the sum div doesn't expand to the remaining height to equal to the content div.
All i want is both divs be in the same height without specifying it.

I totally need a Pure css, and not javascript or table.

Thanks

Comment: there is no pure CSS way to do this, well, without setting specific heights for **both** classes. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960390/how-to-force-an-div-to-extend-down-to-the-bottom-of-the-screen/3960435#3960435

Comment: Good luck with that. What you're trying to do is the holy grail of CSS. There are plenty of hacks to make it pretty close to what you want, but none of them are perfect. I suggest googling it.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a better option for you...

http://bonrouge.com/2c-hf-fixed.php

or check out faux columns:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/

Comment: I've been using faux columns for this for a long time.